# Android simplest way to update UI when parameter changes?

Tags: android, user-interface, observers

The code below works for me but I have to click to see the latest value of the luvText string.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    var luvText = "Luv values"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //val dataBinding: PlainActivityBinding =
        //    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, binding.colourValueText)
        //dataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        binding.viewFinder.setOnClickListener { binding.colourValueText.text = luvText }
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }
```

I have looked at many examples, and tried to copy what they do, but so far without success.

How do the two sorts of binding overlap? I was using viewBinding for the UI, but most of the examples start off using findViewById(). For my experiments, I needed to ask for both in build.gradle...

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
```

I have converted activity_main.xml to a layout. For others that may follow, Android Studio will do this for you if you right click on the first line after the header, select 'Show Context Actions', and pick the layout option. The examples rarely mention this.

Is it necessary? One source uses MutableLiveData and does not need it...

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

This recommends that the MutableLiveData is in a ViewModel() instance. Is this necessary?

My code contains some commented out views for earlier attempts. There seem to be a lot of different and incompatible ways of doing almost the same thing. So, let me tie up this rambling question by asking...

What's the simplest (fewest lines)  way of getting my one TextView to update when the one string variable is changed by the cameraExecutor?

Are the different sets of tools equivalent? Or is there an obvious 'latest and greatest' choice?

PS:

The luvText string is set like this...

```
            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuvAnalyzer { LUV ->
                        // Log.d(TAG, "Average LUV: %.1f %.1f %.1f".format(LUV[0], LUV[1], LUV[2]))
                        luvText = "Average LUV: %.1f %.1f %.1f".format(LUV[0], LUV[1], LUV[2])
                    })
                }
```

The original code (commented out) wrote the new value to the log. I can set the luvText string, but I cannot cause it to be displayed from here, as this is a different thread.

Comment: How does the executor change the value of that class member (`luvText`) in the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution I have found. Deleted code that is not part of the solution is replaced by an ellipsis (...)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var xyzText = MutableLiveData<String>()
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        xyzText.observe(this) {
            binding.colourValueText.text = xyzText.value
        }

    }   
    private fun startCamera() {
        ...
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(...)
            ...

            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, RgbAnalyzer { XYZ ->
                        xyzText.postValue("Average XYZ: %.1f %.1f %.1f".format(XYZ[0], XYZ[1], XYZ[2]))
                    })
                }
 
         }
    }
```

I set string using postValue() because it is generated in another thread. This marks the MutableLiveData as having been changed, and the Observer update the UI.

I have just checked this. The 'dataBinding true' line is not needed in build.gradle.

The TextView binding.colourValueText.text did not need changing, and I have not changed the layout. I cannot promise this does not leak or do something else bad, but it seems to work.